# Play multiple videos like tiktok?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am trying to find a way to play multiple videos, in array, at the same time. Here is an example:

[image]

If you have been on TikTok, you know usually those videos are playing at the same time. I am trying to accomplish something like that. Here is some of my code:

```
  <FlatList
              data={data.vidSlide}
              horizontal={true}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Video', { Video: item })}>
                  <View key={item.id} style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingRight: 5 }}>
                    <Video
                      source={{ uri: item.video }}
                      ref={lo}
                      style={{ borderRadius: 7, width: 115, height: 175 }}
                      onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}
                      onLoad={() => lo.current.playAsync()}
                      resizeMode="cover"
                      isLooping
                    >
                    </Video>
                  </View>
                </Pressable>
              )}
            />
```

This did not work. It showed all the videos, but only one video actually played. I have a feeling it has something to do with the "ref" though. How can I fix this?